# Paso de datos de un puntero a otro

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria, punteros

En mi programa hay que crear una función duplicar que reciba un string y devuelva un puntero a una nuevo string que sea la copia del pasado anteriormente.
Mi programa "funciona" el problema es que si yo al string inicial pasado como argumento a mi función duplicar lo defino dinamicamente, cuando yo libero esa memoria mi string "copia" desaparece y el compilado tira muchos errores y no entiendo porque. ya que si no seria mas facil hacer directamente p=v; y listo.

Dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char*duplicar(char*);
main()
{
 char *p,*v;
 v=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
 v="sip";
 p=duplicar(v);
 free(v);                             //con el free no funciona ?poqueÂ¿
 printf("%s\n",p);
 return 0;
}
char*duplicar(char*v)
{
 int l,i;
 char *k;
 l=strlen(v); 
 if(l==0)
  {
   k=NULL;  
  }
 k=(char*)malloc(l*sizeof(char)); //si malloc falla retorna NULL
 for(i=0;i<l;i++)
  {
   *(k+i)=*(v+i);
  }
 return k;
}
```

Dejo el error devuelto por el compilador

*** Error in `./ej14': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x08048600 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6[0x4a5f871b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6[0x4a5f9460]
./ej14[0x80484f9]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x4a59c5b5]
./ej14[0x80483e1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 10148      /home/knoppix/ej14
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 10148      /home/knoppix/ej14
0804a000-0806b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
4a560000-4a57f000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 25         /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
4a57f000-4a580000 r--p 0001f000 00:0e 25         /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
4a580000-4a581000 rw-p 00020000 00:0e 25         /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
4a583000-4a6f1000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 30         /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
4a6f1000-4a6f2000 ---p 0016e000 00:0e 30         /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
4a6f2000-4a6f4000 r--p 0016e000 00:0e 30         /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
4a6f4000-4a6f5000 rw-p 00170000 00:0e 30         /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
4a6f5000-4a6f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
4b848000-4b864000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 8031       /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
4b864000-4b865000 rw-p 0001b000 00:0e 8031       /UNIONFS/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b774e000-b774f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7760000-b7763000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfefd000-bff1e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
ffffe000-fffff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
Abortado

Comment: ¿Existe algún motivo por el cuál no estás usando strncpy para inicializar o copiar los valores a los char*?

Comment: @ElAsiduo Creo que es parte de la consigna de la tarea.

Comment: @NaCl he visto mucha gente tratando de reinventar la rueda. Prefiero que quede claro.

Comment: @ElAsiduo Yo igual, sin embargo, la ignoracia recae sobre una calculadora cientifica. *"Todos sabemos sacar el `cos(X)` con ella, pero no sabemos hacerlo manualmente"* Supongo que es la logica detras del ejercicio.

Comment: exactamente es la consigna del ejercicio, alguien sabe como porque ocurre eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo `free` sobre un puntero que no ha sido obtenido con `malloc`, `calloc` o `realloc`.

El siguiente programa, mucho más sencillo, tiene el mismo problema :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
 char *v;
 v=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
 v="sip";
 free(v);                             //con el free no funciona ?poqueÂ¿
 return 0;
}
```

`malloc` reserva una zona de memoria de tamaño de 4 chars y devuelve un puntero que apunta a esa zona de memoria y ese puntero es asignado a `v`.

`v="sip"` no copia la cadena `"sip"` a la zona de memoria que es apuntada por `v` sino que asigna a `v` un puntero distinto; este otro puntero apunta a otra zona de memoria en que el compilador ha colocado la cadena `"sip"`. Por tanto el puntero que devolvió `malloc` se pierde.

Cuando se hace `free(v)` en `v` no hay un puntero obtenido con `malloc`, `calloc` o `realloc`; por eso falla.

El siguiente programa sí funciona :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
 char *v;
 v=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
 strcpy(v, "sip" );
 free(v);          //Ahora sí funciona con el free
 return 0;
}
```

En este usamos `strcpy(v, "sip")` en vez de `v="sip"`.
`strcpy` no modifica `v`, `v` sigue apuntando a una zona de memoria de tamaño de 4 chars que devolvió `malloc`. Lo que hace `strcpy` es copiar los cuatro caracteres de la cadena `"sip"` a la zona de memoria que es apuntada por `v`.

Answer (score 1):

C no es mi lenguaje predilecto pero me interesa mucho.

Estuve probando el compilador *online* **rextester**, con la opción **C (gcc)**, una herramienta muy útil, por cierto, y me dijo que el error está en la línea `v="sip";` porque `free` sólo se puede aplicar al montón o *heap*.

***"sip"*** es tomada como constante y el compilador la almacena en la pila o *Stack*, lo que impide el uso de `free`.

Entonces hice una función `str2p` (*stringToPointer*) que asigne los caracteres de la constante literal en una variable:

```c
//gcc 4.9.3

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define    STR_LEN    4    // El tamaño del string, más el caracter nulo '\0'


void str2p (char[], char*, int );    // Asigna los char de char[] en la variable apuntada por char*
char* duplicar ( char* );            // Retorna una copia de los char del argumento char*


int main()
{
    char *p,*v;


    // Reserva memoria para el string.
    v = (char*)malloc(STR_LEN * sizeof(char));

    // Asigna la constante string "sip" a la variable v.
    str2p("sip", v, STR_LEN);
    // Nótese que si la constante fuese más extensa,
    // por ejemplo "sip123", sólo las primeras STR_LEN-1 letras podrán asignarse.       

//    v="sip";    // <-- Error: la constante "sip" va al Stack, lo que impide el free()

    printf("Variable v antes de free(v) = '%s'\n", v);
    printf("Variable p antes de free(v) = '%s'\n", p);

    p = duplicar (v);

    free(v);    // Ahora funciona.

    printf("Variable v después de free(v) = '%s'\n", v);
    printf("Variable p después de free(v) = '%s'\n", p);

    return 0;
}

void str2p (char c[], char* v, int len)
{   
    int t = strlen(c) + 1;    // +1 incluye el caracter nulo '\0'

    // Para evitar desbordes se elige la longitud menor.
    int menor = ((t < len) ? t : len) - 1;

    // Comienza la asignación, letra por letra.
    for (int i=0; i < menor; i++)    v[i] = c[i];            

    // En C es obligatorio que todas las strings terminen en un caracter nulo '\0'
    v[menor] = 0;
}

char* duplicar (char* origen)
{
    char* k;
    int l = strlen(origen) + 1;    // Recordar siempre agregar el +1 para el caracter nulo '\0'

    if ( l == 0 )    k = NULL;
    else             k = (char*)malloc(l*sizeof(char)); //si malloc falla retorna NULL

    if (k == NULL) return NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < l-1; i++ )    k[i] = origen[i];

    return k;
}
```

El ejercicio está guardado en [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/NILZZ73105)